# Character encoding problem UTF8

Tags: html, session, utf-8, character

here is my index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">

  </head>
  <body>

    <center>
        some special character: éá
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is how it looks like in the browser:some special character: ĂŠĂĄ

if in Notepad++ i set it to Convert to UTF-8 then the text looks like it should but then i have the "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by" warning note becouse the BOM characters. if i set the charcter coding to "without BOM" in Notepad++ then the characters are messed up again.

Comment: Save as UTF-8 w/o BOM. This should be supported by the editor.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` you are missing the `-` character.

Comment: @Kevin  <read>if i set the charcter coding to "without BOM" in Notepad++ then the characters are messed up again.</read>

Comment: @ Jaroslav Jandek i have tried it but it doesnt make any difference

Comment: Sorry that I didn't catch that. However, I don't know what to tell you. If Notepad++ is not properly encoding the page without using BOM, then you'll need to find another option.

Answer (score 3):

convert the file to UTF-8 without BOM and then
add this line to our php files at the first line.

`<?php header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8'); ?>`

this will help you i hope.

Comment: unfortuneatly for me helped. dont forget to CONVERT UTF-8 WIHOUT BOM. instead of only changing the charset.

Comment: my code looks now exactly like yours. i tried both with the same result:some special character: ĂŠĂĄ. this mystery drives me crazy!!

Comment: i dont know what is your problem. for me this works with ĂŠĂĄ too.